# Checking internet connection in Android (function comparison)

Tags: android, connectivity

So I am comparing which of the two functions I should implement below.  I know one checks if the phone is connected to the internet vs. checks if you have a connection in general?  Does one work better then the other, what does one do vs. the other?  Do they do the same thing?

Function 1:

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
       try {
          HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
          urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
          urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
          urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
          urlc.connect();
          return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
       } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
       }
    } else {
       Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Function 2:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
    = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, function **1.** requires permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Function **2.** needs

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Function 1.**

- Transfers actual data (bad)
- Doesn't work if DNS servers are dead
- Doesn't work if Google is down (small chance, but not 0%)
- On slow mobile networks, may take quite some time before you get the response (really bad)

In practice, you should only use function **2.** and properly handle failed requests to **YOUR** server

Comment: All answers were good, chose this one because it mentioned best practices.... Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Function 2 has more clear declarative manner, you ask for network availability instead of doing steps to check it (as in Function 1).
In addition, Android 5.0 provides new multi-networking APIs that let your app dynamically scan for available networks with specific capabilities, and establish a connection to them, see [Wireless and Connectivity](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless)

Comment: I tried to +1!  That is pretty cool.  Have you implemented it yet, if so, was it hard?

Comment: i haven't already used this API, but it doesn't look hard to implement :)

Answer (score 1):

i usually use both... like in your case (isNetworkavailable && hasActiveInternetConnection)

the first method will check if there is a connection at all (e.g. there will be none if the phone is in airplane mode) and if that seems to work the second method checks if there can actually be data received through that connection

Answer (score 1):

I know facebook launched a library to check network trafic quality, you can check the github :

https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion use function2 first. If it succeeds call function1.;-)
Function2 will make sure that there is some connection on from the device. If yes then function2 will ping some uri, google in this example. It is useful in situation where the device may be connected to some wifi, but there are still issue in getting connection, etc

The only problem which sometimes may come is in case of connection that is exremely slow. Even if the connection is available, it may say that no connection is available